# Specifying date format in Django templates with L10N for one language

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template I'm displaying a date like:

```
{{ article.published_at|date }}
```

which displays like:

> Nov. 21, 2018

I would like to change this format, *but*:

- I am using Localization, so I don't want to specify a specific date format in the template -- each language will have its own way of displaying dates.
- The Django `DATE_FORMAT` setting [does not have any effect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_FORMAT) when the `L10N` setting is `True`.

So how would I:

1. Use a different format for this date when the current language is English (`en`)
2. Use the current language's default date format when it's not `en`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the filter I've ended up using as a replacement for the built-in [`date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

```
# myapp/templatetags/my_filters.py
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.defaultfilters import date
from django.utils import dateformat
from django.utils.translation import get_language

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(expects_localtime=True, is_safe=False)
def format_date(value):
    if value in (None, ''):
        return ''

    language_code = get_language()

    if language_code == 'en':
        # Language is English, so use the format defined in settings:
        return dateformat.format(value, settings.DATE_FORMAT)
    else:
        # Language is not English, so use language-specific default:
        return date(value)
```

I use the normal [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#date-format) Django setting in `settings.py` to set a custom date format:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'j F Y'
```

This is used if the current language is English. Otherwise the current language's default is used.

Use it like:

```
{% load my_filters %}

{{ article.published_at|format_date }}
```

You could extend this to provide custom formats for additional languages, but this is all I need for now.

I still expected there to be a way to define per-language date formats in settings, so I still feel like I've missed a simpler way of doing this...

Answer (score 1):

Does your template include the `{% load l10n %}` tag?
You can specify the date format already using the tag above and

for example if you were looking for the date to be displayed like:
**1/13/2020**

you wourl do: 
    `your_date|date:'n/j/Y'`

see [Link to the docs for builtins |date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Never much point rolling your own when it already exists, would recommend however considering adding a `date_format="n/j/Y"` in the context. Then you can just right:

`{{ item.date_end|date:date_format }}`

Then you wont have the format specified in the template, plus you can if it's used everywhere create a context processor to define it so it's included in every render. Thus making it super easy to change site wide.

[Create your own context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

Comment: It didn't. I've tried adding it but that doesn't do anything different on its own.

Comment: Try specifying `LANGUAGE_CODE`  (remember it also needs `USE_I18N = True`). If you want your app to dynamically determine language preference, look into [LocaleMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know what you mean. The entire site is working fine in multiple languages, with translations, and the user can switch between language versions.

Comment: Oh, okay then. I misunderstood your question and somehow assumed that you have problems setting up localization in a new application.You can specify how the date will be displayed in the template like so `{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}` ([check docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date)). If you want to customize this for every language you can pass `django.utils.translation.get_language()` to template context and use a simple conditional block. Is this what you had an issue with?

Comment: I don’t know how to describe the problem any better than I have in points 1 and 2 in the question. I don’t want to use a conditional in the template every time I display a date. I guess I’ll have to write my own template filter, but I thought there might be something simpler that I’d missed.

Comment: Imo it's a simple filter and definitely a better solution than a verbose if block every time you want to print a date.